# Does magic healing double non-lethal healing?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, healing

Does magic healing double non-lethal healing? Aka does magical healing heal non-lethal twice since it heals normally then again for non-lethal?

Comment: Is there something you've read or heard that has you believe this might be the case or might not be? (I'm not sure which it is myself but this might be relevant to answerers.)

Comment: Based on the [comments below](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/112645/does-magic-healing-double-non-lethal-healing?noredirect=1#comment272690_112646) the question isn't clear enough yet. Could you [edit] it to clearly and fully describe what you're asking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RAW - No.

Under the [combat rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/#TOC-Nonlethal-Damage) where healing non-lethal damage is covered

> You heal nonlethal damage at the rate of 1 hit point per hour per character level. When a spell or ability cures hit point damage, it also removes an equal amount of nonlethal damage.

Note that it says an equal amount.

Comment: Would the normal healing aspect also take into account is what I'm asking?

Comment: No. Non-lethal heals at its own rate naturally, which is much faster than the normal healing rate of lethal damage.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to the books at the moment, but I found [this](http://www.autarch.co/forums/ask-autarchs/healing-nonlethal-damage):

> "Spells or magical powers that cure hit point damage remove an equal amount of nonlethal damage." Corebook p. 105